# UIViewAutoresizingNone: Resize after rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, autoresizingmask

i have a simple structure for IPAD with an AppDelegate that include a view from a viewController :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    ClockVC *clockVC = [[ClockVC alloc]init];
    clockVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, clockVC.view.bounds.size.width, clockVC.view.bounds.size.height);

    [self.window addSubview:clockVC.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

clockVC has a viewDidLoad defined by this code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
}
```

Bounds of clockVC are defined by IB and override in application:didFinishLaunching...
Width and Height are respectively 200 and 150.

ClockVC implements method for one-step auto-rotation :
/

```
/ Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{  
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                     animations:^{self.view.alpha = 0;}
     ];
}

-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{ 
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 
                     animations:^{self.view.alpha = 1;}
     ];
}
```

At the first load the page is correctly viewed and clockVC view is in position. 
When i rotate clockVC view (whose autoResizeMask is set to UIViewAutoresizingNon)resize to take the entire screen.

Why ?? i'd like to mantain initial size.

Here screenshots of my problem.
Before rotation: 
[image]

After Rotation:
[image]

Comment: i just added `clockVC.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;` to  application:didifinishlaunching into app delegate... but nothing change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the root view for this, add a subview to the view controller's view instead. `UIViewControllers` are typically designed to fill the entire space of their container (the window in this case).

For example, if you would add a `UIViewController` to a `UINavigationController`, the navigation controller takes over the responsibility to size the view controller's view according to the navigation controller's layout (whether the navigation bar is visible etc.). I'm not sure how exactly UIWindow behaves (I think this is not very clearly documented), but in a lot of places in the SDK, a view controller's parent is responsible for the positioning and size of its children (`UIPopoverController`, `UITabBarController` et.al.).

Comment: Would't it just be easier to create 2 nib files one for each position?

Comment: Thank you omz, i can't find something about that on Documentation but  i read only this : 
`In an iOS application, the window object does much of the work associated with changing the current orientation. However, it works in conjunction with the application’s view controllers to determine whether an orientation change should occur at all, and if so, what additional methods should be called to respond to the change. Specifically, it works with the view controller whose root view was most recently added to, or presented in, the window`.