# Why is a window’s subview initially positioned incorrectly, but repositioned correctly after rotation?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Consider the following app delegate entry point:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Custom view controller
    main = [[MainView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
    [self.window addSubview:main.view];

    return YES;
}
```

Everything is Apple stock code, except the “custom view controller” part. There, a custom view controller is grabbed, and effectively added as the main view of the app.

Problem: the widgets in the view are 20px above where they should be. In other words, top 20px of the view’s contents are obscured by the status bar.

But: after rotation, the view and its contents are positioned correctly, and the status bar overlap no longer appears.

What’s going on here? And specifically, what’s the pattern/best practice to make sure that things are positioned correctly also when adding the subview to the window initially?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong method for initializing your UIWindow's frame. Yous should be using `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` for exactly the reason you are talking about. [Read this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html) for more (basically `applicationFrame` takes care of the status bar issue).

Comment: This is not exactly correct, but it lead me to the right place. Changing self.window coordinates gave me more errors after rotating, but I fixed everything by adding this: `main.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];`

Answer (score 1):

I think since you've used `initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` to initialize the frame(height-480) and then added a subview, when the app is launched, it takes up the entire screen(as you've asked it to). But when you rotate it, the frame resizes taking into account the status bar.That's why the problem occurs only once ,ie, the first time. Take a look at this sof question: [UIViewAutoresizingNone: Resize after rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804431/uiviewautoresizingnone-resize-after-rotation).

To make sure that things are positioned correctly also when adding the subview to the window initially, you can define its `frame` size and `origin` before adding it as `subView`.